# PLS-00103 error while creating package with overloading functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

Please help in finding the error while creating the package with overloading functions.

Error shown:

PL-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMOU"when expecting one of the following: language.

PL-00103: Encountered the symbol "Function" when expecting one of the following: end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static member constructor map.

code:

```
create or replace package over_load as

function print_it(numin varchar2) return number is numou number;

begin
numou := to_number(numin, '999,999.00');
dbms_output.put_line(numou);
return numou;

exception
when others then 
dbms_output.put_line('Wrong string format');

return numou;

end;


function print_it(datin date) return varchar2 is datout varchar2(30);

dumcha varchar2(30);
dumdat date;

begin
dumcha := to_char(datin);
dumdat := to_date(dumcha,'FXDD-MON-YYYY');

datout := to_char(datin, 'fmMOn, DD YYYY');
dbms_output.put_line(datout);
return datout;

Exception
when others then 
dbms_output.put_line('Wrong input date format');
return '0';

end;

end;
```

[image]

Comment: -1 How about posting some code instead of dumping a unusable screenshot on us?

Comment: You are trying to define functions in the package specification. You **declare** subprograms in a package specification, you **define** subprograms in the package body(`create [or replace] package body package_name is...`).

Comment: Thanks! Now, I find my question very silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Oracle RDBMS` You **MUST** specify package (for public methods) and package body containing implementation for all public methods and optionally You can add some private methods.

Package specification:

```
create or replace package over_load as

  function print_it(numin varchar2) return number;
  function print_it(datin date) return varchar2;

end;
```

And body:

```
create or replace package body over_load as

  function print_it(numin varchar2) return number is 
    numou number;
  begin
    numou := to_number(numin, '999,999.00');
    dbms_output.put_line(numou);
    return numou;
  exception
    when others then 
      dbms_output.put_line('Wrong string format');
      return numou;
  end;


  function print_it(datin date) return varchar2 is 
    datout varchar2(30);
    dumcha varchar2(30);
    dumdat date;
  begin
    dumcha := to_char(datin);
    dumdat := to_date(dumcha,'FXDD-MON-YYYY');

    datout := to_char(datin, 'fmMOn, DD YYYY');
    dbms_output.put_line(datout);

    return datout;
  exception
    when others then 
      dbms_output.put_line('Wrong input date format');
      return '0';
  end;
end;
```

**NOTE THAT:**
To enable output from DBMS_OUTPUT in SQL*Plus You must enable `serveroutput`:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size 30000;
```